# How to keep string data for having best performance when selecting string list via LINQ by StartsWith and EndsWith queries

Tags: c#, performance, linq, c#-4.0, startswith

Now the question is pretty hard. I have a linq queries like the way below

```
var lstSimilars = from similarWords in lstAllWords

where similarWords.StartsWith(srWordLocal)

select similarWords;

foreach (string srVar in lstSimilars)
{
string srTempWord = srVar.Replace(srWordLocal, "");
if (dtWords.ContainsKey(srTempWord) == true)
{
csWords.updateSplitWord(srWordLocal + ";" + srTempWord, dtWords[srVar]);
}
}

lstSimilars = from similarWords in lstAllWords

where similarWords.EndsWith(srWordLocal)

select similarWords;

foreach (string srVar in lstSimilars)
{
string srTempWord = srVar.Replace(srWordLocal, "");
if (dtWords.ContainsKey(srTempWord) == true)
{
csWords.updateSplitWord(srWordLocal + ";" + srTempWord, dtWords[srVar]);
}
}
```

Now `lstAllWords` is a string list variable generated like the way below

```
        List<string> lstAllWords = new List<string>();


        for (int i = 0; i < dsWordsSplit.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            lstAllWords.Add(dsWordsSplit.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Word"].ToString());
        }
```

My question is how should i keep that Words data for having best LINQ selection performance. I mean currently i am keeping it as a string list. But can i keep it different way and have better performance ?

`dtWords` is a dictionary object

C# C#-4.0 LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is *efficiently* finding words that start or end with given substring,  employing the [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) will help you do that in **O(log(N))** time.

The idea is to put words in two `SortedSet`s:

- one for original words and
- the other for reversed words.

Toy implementation:

```
class WordSet {

    public WordSet(IEnumerable<string> words) {
        m_OriginalWords = new SortedSet<string>(words);
        m_ReverseWords = new SortedSet<string>(words.Select(ReverseString));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Finds all words that start with given prefix.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> FindPrefix(string prefix) {
        return FindImp(m_OriginalWords, prefix);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Finds all words that end with the given suffix.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<string> FindSuffix(string suffix) {
        return FindImp(m_ReverseWords, ReverseString(suffix)).Select(ReverseString);
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> FindImp(SortedSet<string> word_set, string s) {
        if (s.CompareTo(word_set.Max) <= 0) {
            foreach (string word in word_set.GetViewBetween(s, word_set.Max)) {
                if (!word.StartsWith(s))
                    break;
                yield return word;
            }
        }
    }

    static string ReverseString(string src) {
        return new string(src.Reverse().ToArray());
    }

    readonly SortedSet<string> m_OriginalWords;
    readonly SortedSet<string> m_ReverseWords;

}

class Program {

    static void TestImp(string s, IEnumerable<string> words) {
        Console.Write(s);
        foreach (var word in words) {
            Console.Write('\t');
            Console.Write(word);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void TestPrefix(WordSet word_set, string prefix) {
        TestImp(prefix, word_set.FindPrefix(prefix));
    }

    static void TestSuffix(WordSet word_set, string suffix) {
        TestImp(suffix, word_set.FindSuffix(suffix));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var word_set = new WordSet(
            new[] {
                "a",
                "b",
                "ba",
                "baa",
                "bab",
                "bba",
                "bbb",
                "bbc",
            }
        );

        Console.WriteLine("Prefixes:");
        TestPrefix(word_set, "a");
        TestPrefix(word_set, "b");
        TestPrefix(word_set, "ba");
        TestPrefix(word_set, "bb");
        TestPrefix(word_set, "bc");

        Console.WriteLine("\nSuffixes:");
        TestSuffix(word_set, "a");
        TestSuffix(word_set, "b");
        TestSuffix(word_set, "ba");
        TestSuffix(word_set, "bb");
        TestSuffix(word_set, "bc");

    }

}
```

This prints:

```
Prefixes:
a       a
b       b       ba      baa     bab     bba     bbb     bbc
ba      ba      baa     bab
bb      bba     bbb     bbc
bc

Suffixes:
a       a       baa     ba      bba
b       b       bab     bbb
ba      ba      bba
bb      bbb
bc      bbc
```

If you have to search for infixes as well, then the above is not enough - you'll need a suffix tree or array, but this is no picnic implementing correctly **and** efficiently.

---

BTW, If the data happens to be in the database, you can let the DBMS do essentially the same thing by:

- creating a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) or [virtual column](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle11g/oracle_11g_function_based_columns.htm) that is reverse of the original word column,
- indexing **both** original word column and the reversed word column (or, alternatively, using a [function-based index](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_function_based_indexes.htm) if that's what your DBMS supports).
- querying for prefix as: `ORIGINAL_WORD_COLUMN LIKE 'pefix%'`
- and for suffix as: `REVERSED_WORD_COLUMN LIKE 'reversed_suffix%'`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for the answer though i later discovered that i don't need to do both startswith or endswith. I just need one of them. So what would be your best suggestion for doing this. Using C# objects or MS-SQL ? Though your sorted set improved the software already.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG In the client-server environment, client-level filtering requires **all** the rows to be read from server's disk and transferred from server to client. If the server does the filtering, **only** the filtered rows are transferred (and if you did your indexing correctly, only filtered rows are even read from the disk). Obviously, the second scenario scales much better, so always prefer to do the filtering in the database. Whether you'll do it through "naked" SQL and ADO.NET, or through LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework or NHibernate etc... is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

A string list should be sufficiently performant for selecting from, but you're adding some boxing/unboxing operations by selecting into and then iterating over a `var`.  You can use a strongly-typed `List<string>` as your recipient of LINQ query results for a performance boost, but it'll likely only be noticeable for *very* large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I compared SQL server selection and LINQ selection. Currently LINQ is about 18% faster.

Comment: Also when i do that it gives the error at this image : http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/6820/errorjj.png Please look at the image. Because of that error i can not define it as List<string>

Comment: List<string> lstSimilars = (from similarWords in lstAllWords

where similarWords.StartsWith(srWordLocal)

select similarWords).ToList<string>();

Comment: thanks working now though it did not make any speed effect :D

Comment: Sorry, but the boxing information is incorrect.  `var` has nothing to do with boxing.  Strings are reference types, and boxing does not apply to reference types.  Furthermore, if you're only going to iterate the "where" iterator once, there's no performance benefit to creating a list; in fact, there is a performance penalty of allocating the storage for the list.