# Fastest way to select all strings from list starting from

Tags: c#, .net, linq, algorithm

I'm looking for the fastest way to find all strings in a collection starting from a set of characters. I can use sorted collection for this, however I can't find convenient way to do this in .net. Basically I need to find low and high indexes in a collection that meet the criteria.

BinarySearch on List<T> does not guarantee the returned index is that of the 1st element, so one would need to iterate up and down to find all matching strings which is not fast if one has a large list.

There are also Linq methods (with parallel), but I'm not sure which data structure will provide the best results.

List example, ~10M of records:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaba
aaaaaaaaaaaaabc
...
zzzzzzzzzzzzzxx
zzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzza
```

Search for strings starting from: skk...

Result: record indexes from x to y.

UPDATE: strings can have different lengths and are unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of time complexity - you should use a [**trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and not a sorted set or binary search.

Trie will get you a `O(|S|)` time complexity [while sorted set and binary search gets you `O(|S|logn)`] to find the node [let it be `v`] that represents that prefix.

All the strings [paths] in the trie that fit the prefix will "pass" via `v`. By adding `numberOfLeaves` field to each node, you can find out exactly how much leaves [=strings] this node has.

In a single pass - you can also find the index of this `v` [For each node `u` in the path from the root to `v` - sum `numberOfLeaves` for each sibling which is left to `u`].

This requires much more work then using already existing structures, but if the data is huge - it can make your algorithm **much** faster, so you should concider it if performance is an issue and you expect a huge set of strings.

Comment: Wow, trie-- that looks exactly what may be required here. Time for adding elements is not a concern, only fast look up. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a hand-written binary search - one which just doesn't stop when it's found a match; it continues until it's found a single index.

In fact, you don't even have to write the binary search bit yourself - you could create a custom comparer which *never* returns `0`, i.e. if you're looking for "abc" then it treats "abb" as being below the target value, but "abc" as being *above* the target value. This way the `BinarySearch` will *always* return a negative number, which you can then just bit-flip to find the theoretical insertion point for "the string which comes between abb and abc".

You can do the same in reverse (treat "abc" as *lower* than the target value) to find the highest bound.

If you know the format of these strings and it won't have edge cases like Unicode NULL characters, and everything's the same length, you can even do it without writing your own comparer:

```
// This could be done more efficiently :)
string stringJustBelow = target.Substring(0, target.Length - 1) +
                         target[target.Length - 1] + "X";
string stringJustAbove = target + "X"; // Or any character

int lowerBoundInclusive = ~list.BinarySearch(stringJustBelow);
int upperBoundExclusive = ~list.BinarySearch(stringJustAbove);
```

So if you strings are all length 3 and you were searching for "abc" you'd actually look for where "abbX" and "abcX" would be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) and use [GetViewBetween](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801.aspx).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388706/533120) illustrates searching for both prefix and suffix, I'm sure you'll have no trouble adapting it to prefix-only search, if that is indeed what you want.

If you just want to search for a range (not prefix), directly using `GetViewBetween` should suffice.

Comment: +1 Note that the sorted set won't allow duplicate strings, so if the original list contains duplicates some more work will be needed (for example, use a `SortedDictionary<string, int>` where the integer is a duplicate count). Also note that keeping the strings in a SortedSet (or SortedDictionary) instead of a list will avoid allocating large arrays on the large object heap, which can improve the application's memory use.